# How do I populate a Django ManyToMany relationship with a list from a CSV file, only creating entries for the elements in that list?

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv, many-to-many

I've been following the instructions laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768792/how-to-populate-a-manytomany-field-in-django-using-a-csv-file) trying to populate my Django ManyToMany relationship with data from a list from a column of a csv file. The problem is that when I run the popultate.py file, instead of populating Film.actors with the actors specified in the list from the CSV file, it populates Film.actors with every actor in the database. How do I amend it so that it only populates the model with the data from that list?

Here is my models.py file:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    actor_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Film(models.Model):
    film_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor)
```

And here is populate.py:

```
import pandas   
df = read_csv('csv_file.csv')

def populate_film():
    for index, row in in df.iterrows():
        film_csv_id = str(row['IMDb ID'])
        film_name = str(row['Film'])
        film = Film.objects.get_or_create(film_id = film_csv_id, title = film_name)

    #The CSV actors column returns a the list of actor_ids which I query against the Actor model
    list_of_actors = row['Actors']

    for actor_id in list_of_actors:
        actor_object, _ = Actor.objects.get_or_create(imdb_id = actor_id)
        film.actors.add(actor_object)

populate_film()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain your `actor_id` column? Let's say I got three actors with IDs `[0, 1, 2]`, how will the column look like as a string?

Comment: The actor_ids are unique IMDb IDs from https://www.imdb.com/ so the columns look a bit like this: ['nm0305296', 'nm1109153', 'nm0419894']. I have tried making this column the primary key as well and this did not work either.

Comment: Have you ever tried using a [one-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relationship instead of a `CharField`? This directly links an Actor object to a movie and you can add as many actors as you want. That way you don't need to extra handle IDs and all those as you will already have the actor objects in place.

Comment: No but the Actors can belong to several films and the films also include several actors - will that be a problem for the one-to-many relationship?

Comment: One disadvantage of a `one-to-many` is that the actors will be a subset of a movie object, which means that you might need to create several actors with the same name, age, et cetera. **But wait.** If you don't like this, I'll suggest you look at [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field: more complicated to implement at first, but will eventually pay off as an actor can link to multiple movies and a movie can have multiple actors --  no hierachies like `one-to-many`.

Comment: Yes- that is why i was asking about many-to-many relationships in the original question...